# How to combine two possible selector events into a single statement?

Tags: jquery

I am try to combine the statements below so that it reads like "if either of these events happen, perform the function".  I know this is easy, but it's something that I haven't done and that I need to do.

Can you tweak this?

```
$("#FirstName").keyup(function() {
    checkForm();
});
$("#LastName").keyup(function() {
    checkForm();
});
```

Comment: You may also be able to use `$(...).keyup(checkForm);`, to be even terser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#FirstName, #LastName')` should work.

The comma works as a separator, so

```
$("#FirstName, #LastName").keyup(function() {
    checkForm();
});
```

Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: perfect! I knew it was easy. I just couldn't remember how to do it. Thanks!